# Filter x,y coordinates if x or y greater/less than N

Tags: python

I'm struggling to find the right algorithm to filter a list of x,y coordinates (source : `cv2.matchTemplate`).

My data is like: `[(552, 429), (553, 429), (457, 477), (458, 478), (1208, 671), (1209, 671), (467, 712), (468, 712)]`

These coordinates are useful to draw rectangles to locate where template is found in a picture but I need to "click" on this template so I need only one angle. I want to keep only coordinates whose distance is greater or less than N from all other points.

In this picture, I want to keep only red dots coordinates not blue rectangle coordinates.

[image]

Comment: In other words you need to find a bounding rectangle for your points?

Comment: Hello May.D, your question is not clear enough, what do you want again ?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Quite the opposite, I want to keep only one angle of the rectangle, lets say upper left corner (but no mandatory).

Comment: @ManifestMan I edited the question but I'm not sure its clear, I'm not english native.

Comment: @May.D you can provide a picture with random points and desired result of calculation

Comment: @May.D, okay could you reformulate **x or y < N or > N** ?

Comment: I've tried to reformulate and added picture.

Comment: @May.D, this part of your question is unclear **if x or y GREATER/LESS than N**. Could you write here separately what you mean by that, are these two different statements, i hope so ?

Comment: `data = [(552, 429), (553, 429),  (558, 429)]` `n=5`  here I want to keep first and third element because data[2][0] - N > data[0][0]. I need to have a distance of N (for x or y) between all coordinates.

Comment: I think I get it: if you have a top-left point x,y and find at least one of its closest points (x+1,y / x,y+1 / x+1, y+1), filter those three out and keep the top-left only. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that's it. Sorry for unclear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this is the code block you needed.

```
N = 5
result = []
removed = []
for index, (x, y) in enumerate(data):
    if not (x, y) in result and not (x, y) in removed:
        removed += list(filter(lambda c: abs(c[0] - x) < N, data))
        result.append((x, y))
print(result)
```

Comment: I've tried your code with my data and `N = 5` and it either return all coordinates or none.

Comment: because the values in your data all (x,y) values are greater than 5. Can you explain your question more clear, please? Do you want to filter with the 5th index of the list?

Comment: No I dont mean greater than N, I mean that every coordinate should be distant from N (for x or y) from any other coordinates.

Comment: updated the answer could you check it again.

Comment: You forgot to replace `5` with `N` on line 6 with your edit btw

Comment: I've tried your code with this data : `[(540, 403), (541, 403), (542, 403) ...]` and I get this as output `[(540, 403), (541, 403), (542, 403), (540, 404), (541, 404) ...]`. Correct result would be only first coordinates.

Comment: I have updated the code again. Could you send a correct input case and output case please.

Comment: Tried your code, output same thing as input. 

Input : `[(540, 403), (541, 403), (542, 403), (540, 404), (541, 404), (542, 404), (398, 475), (399, 475), (397, 476), (398, 476), (399, 476), (398, 477), (399, 477)]`

Expected output : `[(540, 403),  (398, 475)]`

Comment: @May.D Also point (397, 476) shoud be in the output, because there is no (396,476) or (397,475) or (396,475). Check out my answer...

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky No it should not because both x and y distance is inferior to 5 compared to (398, 475).

Comment: I have updated the code again. I hope It will work for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it should work:

```
data = [(552, 429), (553, 429), (457, 477), (458, 478), (1208, 671), (1209, 671), (467, 712), (468, 712)]
result = []
for item in data:
  topLeftFilter = lambda n: n[0] == item[0] and n[1] == item[1] - 1 or n[0] == item[0] - 1 and n[1] == item[1] or n[0] == item[0] - 1 and n[1] == item[1] - 1
  topLeftPoint = list(filter(topLeftFilter, data))
  if len(topLeftPoint) == 0:
    result.append(item)

print(result)
```

Comment: Not working with these data :

Input : [(287, 6), (288, 6), (286, 7), (287, 7), (385, 56), (386, 56)]

Output : [(287, 6), (286, 7), (385, 56)]

Expected output : [(287, 6), (385, 56)]

Comment: 286,7 does not have any point near itself, why should it be filtered out?

Comment: That's my requirement, I want to filter out coordinates too close from each others.

Comment: So if you find a separate point which does not have neighbors, it should stay, right?

Comment: If so, keep 286,7 :)

Comment: No because there is already (287, 6) so distance inferior to 5

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong. 286,7 is bottom-left relatively to 287,6 - so they're both top-lefts of different boxes with no common edges and don't exclude each other... But it's your decision anyway. Good luck :)